Ansible TASK [Gathering Facts] fails: empty output and no `Escalation succeeded` message
Environment:
Managed Node:

OS: RedHat 9.4 (custom build)
Bash: 5.1.8(1)-release
Sudo: 1.9.5p2
python: 3.9.18

Control Node (laptop):

Python: 3.12.4
Ansible: core 2.16.8

Interactive ssh to the managed node works, ansible user azureuser is listed among sudoers, python versions are installed according to the Ansible support matrix.
Here the output of the sudo -l command:
Matching Defaults entries for azureuser on pkrbase:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME
    HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE
    LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE",
    env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin, use_pty,
    logfile=/var/lib/docker/volumes/custom/logs/host-applications/os/logs/sudo.always

User azureuser may run the following commands on pkrbase:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Steps to reproduce
I'm running the following playbook:
---
- name: Example play
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Test echo
    command: sudo -u root /bin/bash -c 'date +%F\_%T' 

Ansible config:
[defaults]
keep_remote_files = 1

Ansible command I use:
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini -vvv

I got the logs so it hasn't even started executing my Example play:
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3.9 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'{"platform_dist_result": [], "osrelease_content": "NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nVERSION=\\"9.4 (Plow)\\"\\nID=\\"rhel\\"\\nID_LIKE=\\"fedora\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"9.4\\"\\nPLATFORM_ID=\\"platform:el9\\"\\nPRETTY_NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.4 (Plow)\\"\\nANSI_COLOR=\\"0;31\\"\\nLOGO=\\"fedora-logo-icon\\"\\nCPE_NAME=\\"cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:9::baseos\\"\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.redhat.com/\\"\\nDOCUMENTATION_URL=\\"https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugzilla.redhat.com/\\"\\n\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9\\"\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=9.4\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=\\"9.4\\"\\n"}\n', b'')
Using module file /Users/user123/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible-core/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/modules/setup.py
<10.0.1.4> PUT /Users/user123/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-9450178704_88/tmpqkb44u1_ TO /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723619018.964243-94510-198259747562818/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' '[10.0.1.4]'
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'sftp> put /Users/user123/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-9450178704_88/tmpqkb44u1_ /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723619018.964243-94510-198259747562818/AnsiballZ_setup.py\n', b'')
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723619018.964243-94510-198259747562818/ /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723619018.964243-94510-198259747562818/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'', b'')
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' -tt 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-wmursvspsmcexqwpmmpspmfpfuohiivt ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723619018.964243-94510-198259747562818/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'\r\n', b'Shared connection to 10.0.1.4 closed.\r\n')
fatal: [pkrbase]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.0.1.4 closed.\r\n",
            "module_stdout": "\r\n",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 0
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
pkrbase                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

From what I see the failing command
/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-wmursvspsmcexqwpmmpspmfpfuohiivt ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723619018.964243-94510-198259747562818/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"'

produced \r\n as an output but Ansible expects some facts collected by the setup module.
It's not an issue with Python because I tried to run this part /usr/bin/python3 /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723619018.964243-94510-198259747562818/AnsiballZ_setup.py on the managed node over an interactive ssh session and it returned a json payload with ansible facts.
In addition, I tried to experiment with the sudo -H -S -n -u root part to make sure it works. Simply put, I reduced the command to the following form:
sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c 'echo test'  

Nevertheless, the output is \r\n i.e. empty string instead of test. For some unknown reason the top-level sudo command doesn't pass test as an argument to echo. In case of Ansible, it executes echo without passing BECOME-SUCCESS-wmursvspsmcexqwpmmpspmfpfuohiivt and returns, even though, there's another command to run the setup module.
Even if I reduce the command to sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo test' it doesn't work. At the same time it works without sudo: /bin/sh -c 'echo test'.
Here are the logs if testing with gather_facts: false:
PLAY [Example play] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Test echo] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/user123/useful-scripts/logs/playbook.yml:7
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~azureuser && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'/home/azureuser\n', b'\n#####################################################################################\nThis is a private computer system with access restricted to those with authorisation.\n\nIf you are not specifically authorised to access data on this system, disconnect now.\n\nAll information and communications on this system are subject to review, monitoring\nand recording at any time without notice or permission.\n\nUnauthorised use or access may be subject to prosecution or disciplinary action.\n#####################################################################################\n')
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817="` echo /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817=/home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817\n', b'')
<pkrbase> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.12'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.11'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.10'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.9'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.8'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python3.9\n/usr/bin/python3\n/usr/libexec/platform-python\n/usr/bin/python\n/usr/bin/python\nENDFOUND\n', b'')
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3.9 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'{"platform_dist_result": [], "osrelease_content": "NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nVERSION=\\"9.4 (Plow)\\"\\nID=\\"rhel\\"\\nID_LIKE=\\"fedora\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"9.4\\"\\nPLATFORM_ID=\\"platform:el9\\"\\nPRETTY_NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.4 (Plow)\\"\\nANSI_COLOR=\\"0;31\\"\\nLOGO=\\"fedora-logo-icon\\"\\nCPE_NAME=\\"cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:9::baseos\\"\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.redhat.com/\\"\\nDOCUMENTATION_URL=\\"https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugzilla.redhat.com/\\"\\n\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9\\"\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=9.4\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=\\"9.4\\"\\n"}\n', b'')
Using module file /Users/user123/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible-core/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/modules/command.py
<10.0.1.4> PUT /Users/user123/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-61679h1ln530u/tmpcmult7lb TO /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817/AnsiballZ_command.py
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' '[10.0.1.4]'
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'sftp> put /Users/user123/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-61679h1ln530u/tmpcmult7lb /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', b'')
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817/ /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'', b'')
<10.0.1.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: azureuser
<10.0.1.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/user123/Downloads/baseimage-deb.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="azureuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o 'ControlPath="/Users/user123/.ansible/cp/0de1294de0"' -tt 10.0.1.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-hnsuqsehasujvbyjpxelzalzyeljvcid ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/azureuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723631459.373294-61698-98530118215817/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.1.4> (0, b'\r\n', b'Shared connection to 10.0.1.4 closed.\r\n')
fatal: [pkrbase]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.0.1.4 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
pkrbase                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

This time Ansible gets to my playbook but fails on privilige escalation as before

For gathering facts have you try to run ansible all -i inventory -m setup

@RomeoNinov yes, it is successful

Alex, does that answer your question?

@RomeoNinov no, because my playbook still fails

Alex, you do not need playbook to gather facts, the command above do this.

@RomeoNinov please check the last logs when I disabled gather_facts. There's still a problem regarding privilege escalation

Add after become line become_user;

@RomeoNinov it didn't help. Actually, the issue was in a wrapper script over sudo. It was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78867421/arguments-not-passed-to-bash-shell-called-via-sudo#comment139062650_78867421

Maybe you should ask yourself why you use sudo when you evaluate privileges with become?

@RomeoNinov I agree, it looks excessive
